# Can you Run winform app in the cloud as a process?

Tags: winforms, azure, cloud

Currently, I have full access to a local Windows IIS System in which we execute a windows forms application as a processes in which the winform app runs and takes a screen shot of itself and the web call returns the URL of the saved image. The full process looks like -

- User navigates to webpage
- User inputs variables on web page and submits it to IIS end point.
- IIS takes variables, runs Process.Start on winform app passing in variables.
- IIS returns the URL from the screen capture of the winform app.

Is this something that is doable on Azure or Amazon? I'd like to put this in the cloud but I'm not sure if security restrictions would prevent an app like this from being executed as we had to give specific permissions to get this to work.

Answer (score -1):

If you do this now on a server with IIS, you would be able to do it in the cloud (azure or amazon although I have no amazon experience so I'm guessing). The real question is what would you have to deploy. In this case, you cannot use an app service as your platform for this, you would have to run it in a virtual machine with IIS and configure everything as you do now. Or, if you are adventurous and need load balancing, etc. you could try a virtual machine scale set.

One caveat, since I do not know what the windows application does, what it depends on, you may need to put in some networking configuration if the windows app communicates back to an on-prem database or file store.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I thought I'd reach out into the community first to see if others thought it was feasible. I think the caveat is, the winform has got to run it's graphics in the background and the winform is very simple. Just needs to run itself, and screen capture itself.